# I've Done V3 grammar

Tags: grammar

I've seen a lot of people say

> "I've done seen you...."

what does it mean, i know what the exact meaning of it but what's the format of that type of sentences/grammar? And give me some examples how can i use the sentence by the format that you've given to me.

Comment: I'm not sure I've *ever* seen that construction. There's the dialectal AAVE usage *I **done** seen him*, but that's really their version of mainstream speakers' Present Perfect *(I **have** seen him)*, as opposed to Simple Past *(I **saw** him)*. Regardless of whether anyone else thinks the cited construction has any significant prevalence, I suggest you avoid it. No "competent" native speaker would endorse it.

Comment: Perhaps what you're seeing is examples from writers trying to indicate that their characters are "rustic, uneducated", but who aren't aware that AAVE and similar dialects don't normally use mainstream perfect forms at all.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Completive *done* in AAVE and Southern vernacular AmE is not the same thing as the perfect, which serves primarily to indicate anteriority.  *A Handbook of Varieties of English* says "This auxiliary *done* in a verb phrase may aspectually mark a completed action or event, and may also designate intensity." (p.235) and gives the following examples: "He **done asked** her to marry him" "I **done told** you to take your shoes off before walkin' on that carpet".  Anyway, I've never heard the OP's form before.

Comment: @snailplane: All I can say is although I'm not *that* familiar with AAVE, I'm pretty confident most of its speakers would rarely if ever use the standard perfect form *I have seen him*. I've no idea if they'd have a preference for (or semantic distinction) between *I done saw him* and *I done seen him*, but to me at least it sounds like auxiliary  ***done*** there is similar to mainstream ***have***. And OP's example just looks like a misguided attempt to conjoin two mutually incompatible usages (perhaps some kind of "hypercorrection"?).

Answer (score 1):

You do not say what are the demographics of this "lot of people" using this construction. Nor do you give the social context in which the construction is used.

In any case, it is not a construction used generally in informal conversation in the US or by educated native speakers in serious writing in either the US or UK. There are no circumstances when you need to use that construction when addressing speakers of standard English. In fact, if you do use it, many native speakers will think that your English is simply defective.

Answer (score 1):

This is called the **perfective done** or **completive done**.  It indicates that an action is completed or finished, and is often used to emphasize the completion.  For example, someone might say  "I *done told* him already" to mean what we would express in "mainstream" English as "I *have* told him already."

It is not part of standard English grammar.  It is a feature of (among other dialects) Southern US English and African-American Vernacular English, mostly in spoken use, not in written use.  I would not recommend you use this grammar unless you are around other people who use it regularly and unless you really feel that you understand it completely; otherwise it may be taken as mocking or ignorant.

References:

- http://www.americanenglishwiley.com/appendix.html (look for "completive done")
- [Is there a name for the Southern verb form “done” + past tense?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/389375/is-there-a-name-for-the-southern-verb-form-done-past-tense)
- My in-laws are from the Deep South of the US, and I done visited them just the other week, and believe me they still do use "done"...

Comment: This is an excellent answer, which I have voted for. However, I am uncertain whether it is completely on point. The OP appears to be talking about a sort of double perfect consisting of an inflected form of "have," past participle of "do, and past participle of the operative verb. In my admittedly limited experience, that is not a common structure in any variant of US English. At the end of the day, however, I concur wholeheartedly with this answer's conclusion: be very wary of using this construction.